# How to load a PHP page and then check it for errors prior saving it?

Tags: php

I want to check if a PHP page has errors prior saving that page on the server. Now I have tried exec method, but it is blocked by my webhosting. Can I save page to a local file and then use curl_init / curl_exec to get the page response and try to parse for php errors? I mean is it possible to use local file with curl_init?

Just to be more clearer, pages are created/ loaded and changed by another PHP page (an editor). So in WYSIWYG editor user creates a PHP page and save it to the server, I want to check if that page is without errors before saving it.

Thanks,
Dejan

This image I post only to emphasize that is custom built html/php editor in question where savings take place.
[image: My html/php editor, so everything happens online (just to make it clear)]

Comment: So the user of your Web application submits PHP code, and you would like to check if the code contains errors before saving it to database/filesystem/etc. I'm afraid, there is no absolutely safe way to perform such kind of task. You can check for syntax errors with static analysis tools such as PHPMD, PHPSTAN, PHAN, etc. But in order to check for all kinds of errors, you'd need to run the code in different contexts/test cases (the stuff is normally run by [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) tools)

Comment: You'd have to build syntax checking into the editor like any other IDE does

Comment: I will save that page locally and try to open it with curl, fetch result and parse it for errors, that is what I will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue with curl:

Excerpt:

```
...
      $data = $_POST['editordata'];
      try {
        file_put_contents(APPPATH . "views/test.php", $data);
        $ch = curl_init(base_url() . "/test");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if (strpos($content, 'A PHP Error was encountered') !== false){
          echo '<div class="dont-break-out" style="color:palevioletred">' . $pages_val . ' ' . $this->lang->line('page_with_error') . '!</div>';        
        }
        else {
...
```